# System Catalog vs Information Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

When looking at SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which one is better and why? Are there cases where we should use one over the other?

I can't tell the difference between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is there for compatibility, it doesn't expose all the information about objects on the instance.

`sys` however, fully exposes any relevant information, though you do need to write more SQL. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is "easier" to use for new users, as something like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` contains the names of the table, schema, the column and the data type in objects. To get that with `sys` you would have to use `sys.schemas`, `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` and `sys.types`.

There *used* to be a note on SQL Server's documentation on the column `TABLE_SCHEMA` to suggest it could be wrong. This was changed earlier this year as I questioned it on their [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/4188). The note now states that the information may be incomplete, not incorrect. Again, this is because `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` doesn't expose all the information about the objects, which `sys` does.

Comment: are you sure INFORMATION_SCHEMA is there for back compatibility? I read [it's SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) and will be there for foreseeable future with upgrading expected for many vendors.

Comment: B̶a̶c̶k *compatibilty* is probably a better phrase, @XuShaoyang .

Answer (score 4):

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables are standard tables (well views) that provide relatively consistent descriptions of the database.  They are available in many databases.

The system catalog is specific to SQL Server.  I suppose that those tables could change between releases, although that doesn't really happen.

My preference is to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables for basic stuff -- like what tables are in the database and what columns are in the tables.

The system tables are more powerful and designed specifically for SQL Server, so there are other cases where you need to use those.